# key combination in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm developing an extension for chrome that access a website. I was wondering if I could use a key combination to launch that website.

Manifest:

```
{
    "name": "name",
    "version": "1.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "description",
        "icons": {
          "16": "icon_16.png",
          "48": "icon_48.png",
          "128": "icon_128.png"
        },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon_48.png"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
    //START UPDATE
    "commands": {
      "toggle-feature-foo": {
        "suggested_key": {
          "default": "Ctrl+Shift+5"
        },
        "description": "Toggle feature foo",
        "global": true
      }
    },
    //END UPDATE
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "contextMenus"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I've updated the code but it's not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keyboard shortcuts in Chrome extensions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305318/keyboard-shortcuts-in-chrome-extensions)

Comment: @wOxxOm nope. this one is related to the [commands API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands)

Comment: @vagaroso, I'm not following you. The link has an answer exactly about the commands API. There are several other duplicates so you may find a better one if you like. And anyway there's no need for another answer.

Comment: Even the first result when googling the question title points to the commands API documentation which has a complete implementation (all that's needed is a few minutes to actually read several paragraphs and copypaste the code) so I would rather see this question completely deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only setting up the command on your manifest file isn't enough.
You need to listen to the command too and implement what happens next...

From the docs:

```
 chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
      console.log('Command:', command);
 });
```

But from your question I'm assuming you're trying to put a keybinding to open a page action or browser action. If it's that the case, unfortunately this is not possible since these buttons [require a click to be activated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087204/in-a-chrome-extension-is-there-a-way-to-programatically-click-the-pageaction-b).